# CSS - Allign Images on page

Tags: css, html

on the site au.advfn.com/forex/charts I am trying to centre-allign the four stock charts that are currently alligned left.

There are in the `div id="container"`

I am very new to css, how can I do this?

Comment: can you share your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's impossible, because those charts are currently floating to the left to fill up a horizontal space before the next one goes to some space below, which will break when you try to align them differently. You _can_ choose to keep two charts per line, but then that solution will not be flexible.

Comment: Hey @klaar, thanks for your advice. What would be the best way to fix that?

Comment: Actually it might be possible using CCS3 flexboxes, like here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Answer (score 1):

If your charts are in a div add this to a div:

```
#divwithcharts{
   width: x; //your width
   margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS changes

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 950px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
div.chart {
    width: 338px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and delete div whose id is "one"

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that :), should your "text-aling" say "text-align"

Comment: edited my answer it is `text-align`

Answer (score 0):

You have div with "one" id floated right, move it away, then remove the (float:right) from "chart" css class, add (display:inline-block) then add `<center>` tag after the container div. then you will get the below rendering.

[image]

Comment: Hey @Khaled, when you say "move it away" what do you mean

Comment: Yes sorry i mean change the location to absolute or change the html location below or above the container if it is suitable.